# Express PATCH Request with AJAX: syntax error at or near "("

Tags: ajax, postgresql, express, syntax-error, httprequest

I'm trying to edit an entry within my table using a PATCH request with AJAX, however I'm receiving the following error:

```
error: syntax error at or near "("
    at Connection.parseE (...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:553:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:378:19)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:119:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)`enter code here`
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
```

I believe I've localized the issue. I'm using a PostgreSQL syntax checker, which says:

```
Error(s), warning(s):

42601: syntax error at or near "("
```

Here's the query:

```
UPDATE characters SET COALESCE($1, name), COALESCE($2, role), COALESCE($3, age), COALESCE($4, gender), COALESCE($5, race), COALESCE($6, nationality) WHERE id=$7;
```

Is the query the issue? If not, what do you suggest I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What is your `UPDATE` trying to do with those `COALESCE` calls? Do you mean "set `name` to `$1` if `$1` is not `NULL` and leave `name` alone if `$1` is `NULL`"?

Comment: `UPDATE characters SET name=COALESCE($1, name),` ... et cetera